# How to convert string to nested json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

How to convert following string to json array object. `jQuery.parseJSON()` doesn't work in my case

```
{ 
  label: \"test 1\", 
  expanded: true, 
  items: [ 
    { 
      selected: true, 
      label: \"<a onclick=  
'sendEndpoint(&quot;https://contoso/Test1/&quot;,&quot;List 1&quot;);' > test12 1 < /a>\" 
    },{
      label: \ "<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/Test11/&quot;,&quot;test222&quot;);'>  
      test222 < /a>\" 
    },{
      label: \ "<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/test33/&quot;,&quot;testt 3&quot;);'>testt 3</a>\" 
    },{
      label: \ "tesst 2\", items: [ { label: \"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/tessst&quot;,&quot;tesst 1 & quot;);'>tesst</a>\", 
    }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON doesn't work, because that is not JSON. Whatever has spat that string out has escaped the slashes.

Comment: Where does this come from? Fixing the source might help. It's not JSON because the properties aren't quoted.

Comment: I am get it form a column in database.  stripping the slashes will work?

Comment: No. You still need the keys/values (where appropriate) in double quotes.

Comment: I tried without quotes.Doesn't work. What is the correct string

Comment: tidy code and modified question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems in the JSON string that you have pasted.

1. There is an extra "," at the end of the final "label".The logic can be modified in a way that it does not add a "," by default at the end of json key value and it adds only if there is another key value in the JSON object.
2. By using  `jQuery.parseJSON()` your intention is to parse the provided string as a JSON object. If so then both the key and value should be enclosed with a "" (double quote).

On resolving both the issues the final string would be,

```
{ \"label\": \"test 1\", \"expanded\": true, \"items\": [ { \"selected\": true, \"label\": \"<a onclick='sendEndpoint(&quot;https://contoso/Test1/&quot;,&quot;List 1&quot;);'>test12 1</a>\" }, { \"label\": \"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/Test11/&quot;,&quot;test222&quot;);'>test222</a>\" }, { \"label\": \"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/test33/&quot;,&quot;testt 3&quot;);'>testt 3</a>\" },{ \"label\": \"tesst 2\", \"items\": [ { \"label\": \"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/tessst&quot;,&quot;tesst 1&quot;);'>tesst</a>\", } ] } ] }
```

```js
{
   "label":"test 1",
   "expanded":true,
   "items":[
      {
         "selected":true,
         "label":"<a onclick='sendEndpoint(&quot;https://contoso/Test1/&quot;,&quot;List 1&quot;);'>test12 1</a>"
      },
      {
         "label":"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/Test11/&quot;,&quot;test222&quot;);'>test222</a>"
      },
      {
         "label":"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/test33/&quot;,&quot;testt 3&quot;);'>testt 3</a>"
      },
      {
         "label":"tesst 2",
         "items":[
            {
               "label":"<a onclick='send(&quot;https://contoso/tessst&quot;,&quot;tesst 1&quot;);'>tesst</a>"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```